# Why am i getting this error trying to add trap to my textRPG

Tags: python, text, adventure

I have been trying to add traps to my TextRPG I have something I think will work with a little bit of debugging but the first bug that I ran into is.

TypeError: **init**() should return None, not 'str'

the error is coming from this.

```
 class TrapRoomTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    r = random.randint(1,2)
    if r == 1:
        self.trap = items.PitFall()

        self.tripped_text = "The open hole of a Pit Fall trap obstructs the tunnel."

        self.set_text = "The floor in this hallway is unusually clean."

    else:
        return"""
        Looks like more bare stone...
        """
    super().__init__(x, y)

def modify_player(self,player):
    if not self.trap.is_tripped():
        player.hp = player.hp - self.items.damage
        print("You stumbled into a trap!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\nTrap does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".
              format(self.items.damage, player.hp))

def intro_text(self):
    text = self.tripped_text if self.items.is_tripped() else self.set_text
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return text
```

when i comment out this block of code everything runs as it should. I'm at a loss as to what to do about it. ill post a link to the github repo the code is in world.py starts on line 146.

https://github.com/GusRobins60/AdventureGame.git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__init__` method in python should only used be used to initialize the class variables. You are returning a string from it, which you **should not do**.

You can either remove the return statement or set the string to another variable. Here is an example of what you can probably do:

```
class TrapRoomTile(MapTile):
def __init__(self, x, y):
    r = random.randint(1,2)
    if r == 1:
        self.trap = items.PitFall()

        self.tripped_text = "The open hole of a Pit Fall trap obstructs the tunnel."

        self.set_text = "The floor in this hallway is unusually clean."

    else:
        self.set_text = "Looks like more bare stone..."
    super().__init__(x, y)

def modify_player(self,player):
    if not self.trap.is_tripped():
        player.hp = player.hp - self.items.damage
        print("You stumbled into a trap!")
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\nTrap does {} damage. You have {} HP remaining.".
              format(self.items.damage, player.hp))

def intro_text(self):
    text = self.tripped_text if self.trap.is_tripped() else self.set_text
    time.sleep(0.1)
    return text
```